# creating objects - include key if value set

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

It's common that I want to build up an object like so:

```
const test = {
  key1: value1,
  key2: value2,
  key3: value3,
  key4: value4,
}
```

However, say if `value3` is `undefined` how can I succinctly omit `key3`?

Currently I'm doing something like:

```
const test = {
  key1: value1,
  key2: value2,
  key4: value4,
}

if (value3) test.key3 = value3;
```

But there are situations where there are quite a few values that may be `undefined` and so I'm wondering if there is a way to just not return keys if the value is `undefined` to avoid a whole load of conditionals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` with `Array.reduce` to only collect values that aren't undefined:

```js
const test = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2',
  key4: undefined,
}

const onlyPopulated = Object.keys(test).reduce((p, key) => {
  if (typeof test[key] !== 'undefined') {
    p[key] = test[key];
  }
  return p;
}, {});

console.log(onlyPopulated)
```

Comment: That's the ticket. I haven't used `reduce()` before. Good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use jQuery, then you could use extend as shown below
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Basically, what extend does is merge the second object supplied into the first object. However, it doesn't merge null or undefined properties. So I think it would match your use-case well and is quite clean.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.extend demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="log"></div>
 
<script>
var object1 = {
};
var test = {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    key3: undefined,
    key4: 4,
}
 
// Merge test into object1
$.extend( object1, test );
 
// Assuming JSON.stringify - not available in IE<8
$( "#log" ).append( JSON.stringify( object1 ) );
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In practice I would probably use a technique similar to those already mentioned in other answers. However, just for fun...

If all the values in your object can safely be converted to JSON then a concise way of achieving the desired result would be using `stringify` and `parse`:

```js
var data = {
    key1: 'string',
    key2: 34,
    key3: undefined,
    key4: [{key: 'nested'}],
    key5: null
};

data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

console.log(data);
```

`JSON.stringify` skips `undefined`, though it also skips other value types such as functions. `null` would still be included.

Of course it wouldn't be immediately clear to anyone maintaining the code why you were doing this, they would most likely assume you were taking a defensive copy to avoid reference problems.